# Multiple with_items for copy module

Tags: ansible

I am trying to create switch backups. And i want to create dynamic files based on config output and switch hostname.
As an example, the configuration of switch1 should be saved in file names hostname1, config of switch2 should be saved in file names hostname2 and so on.
I am getting the hostnames from the switches from a file.

And my problem is, that the config of switch1 gets saved in file hostname1, hostname2 etc.
How can I loop the variables correctly to get the right config in the right file?

My current playbook looks like this:

```
    ---
    - hosts: cisco
      connection: local
      gather_facts: false

      vars:
        backup_path: /etc/ansible/tests

        cli:
          host: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
          username: test
          password: test

      tasks:
        - name: show run on  switches
          ios_command:
            commands: show running-config
            provider: "{{ cli }}"
          register: config

        - name: creating folder
          file:
            path: "{{ backup_path }}"
            state: directory
          run_once: yes

       - name: get hostnames
         become: yes
         shell: cat /etc/ansible/tests/hostname_ios.txt
         register: hostnames

      - name: copy config
        copy:
          content: "{{ config.stdout[0] }}"
          dest: "{{ backup_path }}/{{ item }}.txt"
        with_together:  "{{ hostnames.stdout_lines }}"
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Rely on Ansible native host loop instead of inventing your own one.

It's as simple as:

```
- name: show run on  switches
  ios_command:
    commands: show running-config
    provider: "{{ cli }}"
  register: config

- name: copy config
  copy:
    content: "{{ config.stdout[0] }}"
    dest: "{{ backup_path }}/{{ inventory_hostname }}.txt"
```

Comment: thanks for the answer! but i dont want the ip address to be extend to the filename. i want the actual hostname name from the switch like, "test-switch1" to be extened to the filename. Is there any way to build this loop with "with_items"?

Comment: Then define the names in the inventory. You can have both: IP address and your own name.

Comment: Didn't think about that. i will give it a try. But how can i access my own name from my inventory in a playbook?

Comment: So, i am getting an name resolution error. I defined my hosts in my inventory like this: test-switch1 ansible_host=ip

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it running.
Defined names in my inventory as followed:

```
    test-switch1 ansible_host=ip
```

Changed the host var in my playbook

```
  vars:
    backup_path: /etc/ansible/tests

    cli:
      host: "{{ ansible_host }}"
      username: test
      password: test
```

And then executing my tasks:

```
    - name: show run on  switches
      ios_command:
        commands: show running-config
        provider: "{{ cli }}"
      register: config

    - name: copy config
      copy:
        content: "{{ config.stdout[0] }}"
        dest: "{{ backup_path }}/{{ inventory_hostname }}.txt"
```